# How to export Rich-Text to CSV?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We want to export Visualforce page to CSV.
So, we use this code.
But, Rich-Text field contains 「?」.
Why it occured?
I found DEBUG-LOG did NOT contain 「?」.
Please help us..

1.In Visualforce Page, Users can search record and export this listview by apex.
2.This 「note」 field is Rich-Text area.
3.Open by Excel, field value contains 「?」.

・note__c value : 「Penalty　0円​」
・SampleVisualforce.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="SampleController" action="{!init}" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:form id="form1">
        <apex:pageBlock title="search">            
            <div class="search_condition">
                <apex:pageblockSection id="conditionSection" title="検索" columns="3" collapsible="false">

                    <apex:inputText label="serialNo：" value="{!condition.serialNo}" />                    
                    <apex:inputText label="appName："  value="{!condition.appName}"/>

                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </div>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="buttonSection" location="bottom" >
                <apex:commandButton value=" search " action="{!search}" />
                <apex:commandButton value=" clear " action="{!clear}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:commandButton value=" Csv Download " action="{!csvDownload}"/>
            <apex:pageblockTable id="resultTable" value="{!resultsList}" var="o" frame="box">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">serialNo</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField style="width:150px" value="{!o.Name}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">serialNo</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputField style="width:150px" value="{!o.note__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

・SampleController.apxc

```
public without sharing class SampleController {

    // 抽出対象となるフィールドリスト
    static List<String> TARGET_FIELDS = new List<String>{
        'Name'                      
            ,'note__c'              
            };  


                public SearchCondition condition{ get;set; }        
    public List<TerminationEntry__c> resultsList { get;set; }       


    /**
* init
*/
    public void init(){
        this.condition = new SearchCondition();
        this.resultsList = new List<TerminationEntry__c>();
        search();
    }

    /**
* clear
*/
    public PageReference clear(){
        init();
        return null;
    }

    /**
* search
*/
    public PageReference search() {

        // SOQL
        String soqlQuery = condition.getSoqlQuery();
        System.debug('soqlQuery' + soqlQuery);

        try{
            this.resultsList = database.query(soqlQuery);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('e:' + e);
        }
        return null;
    }



    /**
* 検索条件を管理するクラス
*/ 
    public Class SearchCondition {

        private Time JST_AM0 = Time.newInstance(9, 0, 0, 0);  

        /*
* 検索条件の入力フィールド用
*/
        public String serialNo {get;set;}       // 申込番号
        public String appName {get;set;}        // 申込内容        
        public String sortkey { get;set; }          // ソートキー
        public String order { get;set; }            // ソート順

        public SearchCondition() {            
            // デフォルトは作成日の降順とする
            sortkey = 'CreatedDate';
            order = 'DESC';

        }

        // 最終的なSOQLを生成
        public String getSoqlQuery(){
            List<String> param = new String[]{ getFieldList(), getWhere(), getOrder() };
                return String.format('SELECT {0} FROM TerminationEntry__c {1} {2} LIMIT 10', param);
        }

        // SELECT対象フィールド
        private String getFieldList(){
            return String.join(TARGET_FIELDS, ',');
        }

        // WHERE句作成
        private String getWhere(){
            List<String> param = new String[]{ };

                // 申込番号
                if( !String.isBlank(String.valueOf(this.serialNo)) ){
                    param.add('serialNo__c LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(this.serialNo) + '%\'');
                }

            if(param.isEmpty()){
                return '';
            }

            return 'WHERE ' + String.join(param, ' AND ');

        }

        // ORDERBY句作成
        private String getOrder(){
            List<String> param = new String[]{ sortkey, order };
                return String.format('ORDER BY {0} {1} NULLS LAST', param);
        }
    }



    /** CSV data*/
    public List<CSVRow> csvRows{get; private set;}
    public String dt { get;set; }


    /** CSVデータ(ファイル出力用)*/
    public PageReference csvDownload() {
        csvRows = new List<CSVRow>();
        dt = String.valueOf(DateTime.now().format('yyyyMMddHHmm'));

        // CSV用リスト
        List<TerminationEntry__c> csvList = this.resultsList;


        List<String> rname = new List<String>();
        rname.add('serialNo');
        rname.add('note');

        //ファイル出力用のリストへ格納
        CSVRow rows = new CSVRow();
        rows.columns = editCsvRow(rname);
        csvRows.add(rows);

        for(TerminationEntry__c term : csvList){

            //行データを格納するリスト
            List<String> l = new List<String>();
            l.add('"' + term.Name  + '"');
            System.debug(term.note__c);
            System.debug('term.note__c.stripHtmlTags() ' + term.note__c.stripHtmlTags() );
            l.add('"' + term.note__c.stripHtmlTags() + '"');


            //ファイル出力用のリストへ格納
            CSVRow row = new CSVRow();
            row.columns = editCsvRow(l);
            csvRows.add(row);
        }        
        return Page.SampleVisualforce2.setRedirect(false);
    }

    private String editCsvRow(List<String> l){
        String str = '';
        for(integer i = 0; i<l.size(); i++){
            if(i != l.size() - 1){
                str += l.get(i) + ',';
            }else{
                str += l.get(i) + '\n';
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    /** CSV class */
    public class CSVRow{
        public String columns{get;set;}
        public CSVRow(){
            columns = '';
        }
    }
}
```

・DEBUG LOG
[image]

・CSV
[image]

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Excel's handling of UTF-8. You could try to see if there's any anomalies in the CSV output from Salesforce by encoding it as Base64 (which can help capture invisible characters and things like UTF-8 continuation bytes) and then decode as binary/hex.

Comment: I find LibreOffice is often useful for working with non-Roman CSVs.